# How to add seekbar to Android menu items?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-menu, android-seekbar

I'm trying to add seekbars to menu items. I've a `listview` holding `textviews`. I need to add seekbars to menu items so that if user changes font increase seekbar then `listview`'s `textview` items size should be increased.

Similarly, I need to add brightness seek bar also to menu items.

I've implemented customer adapter with `getView()` to display text view rows. How I can achieve above functionality? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

The option menu cannot be edited. By selecting option it can drawn in layout.
 [Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469334/seekbar-in-options-menu)

Comment: Thanks Narendra. Since I'm new to android, I was unable to get the concept stated there. So could you please elaborate on this. Am I need to add write click actions in onKeyDown() method ?